# leanback: ImageViewCard how make info block transparent?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I'm building Android TV app, have issue with transparent background for ImageViewCard in case of selected state, please see image bellow:

[image]

I set transparent background in code:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder")
    val v = ImageCardView(parent.context)
    v.background = ColorDrawable(parent.context.resources.getColor(R.color.trans))
    v.isFocusable = true
    v.infoAreaBackground = ColorDrawable(parent.context.resources.getColor(R.color.trans))
    v.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
    v.cardType = BaseCardView.CARD_TYPE_INFO_UNDER
    v.setInfoAreaBackgroundColor(parent.context.resources.getColor(R.color.trans))
    v.setBackgroundColor(parent.context.resources.getColor(R.color.trans))

    v.setOnFocusChangeListener({ view: View, b: Boolean ->
        v.background = ColorDrawable(parent.context.resources.getColor(R.color.trans))
        v.isFocusable = true
        v.infoAreaBackground = ColorDrawable(parent.context.resources.getColor(R.color.trans))
        v.infoAreaBackground = ColorDrawable(parent.context.resources.getColor(R.color.trans))
    })
```

What is proper way to do it? How make transparent background for selected state? 
Any references to the styles for ImageCardView are warmly welcomed.

Comment: try  this:setBackgroundColor(0)
                background = null

Answer (score 1):

So, I found what was the issue. Added my cards into the ListRowPresenter. To do not see such item inside, it's necessary call setShadowEnabled(false) - in Java or set property in Kotlin

```
val lrp = ListRowPresenter()
lrp.shadowEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things you can do

1st Thing :-

```
 cardView.setInfoVisibility(View.GONE);
```

2nd Things :-
For this you need to do your custom cards. 
Here is the brief how it can be done.

Step 1: Create one view_holder.xml file in layouts.

Step 2: Create a Cardview extending the  BindableCardView<"custom object">
     a) Here you will get bind("custom object") Override method 
     b)Here another method

```
@Override
protected int getLayoutResource() {
    return R.layout.episode_card_view;
}
```

Step 3 : Create a class (say CustomePresenter.class) extending Presenter

```
public class EpisodeCardRepresenter extends Presenter{ @Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent) {
    return new ViewHolder(new CardView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, Object item) {
    ((CardView) viewHolder.view).bind(("custom object") item);

}}
```

Step 3 : Then add this presenter in class needed inside the 
 new ArrayObjectAdapter(new CustomePresenter())

It's done Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can doit on your CardPresenter's onBindViewHolder method

```
((ImageCardView) viewHolder.view).setInfoAreaBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.lb_tv_white));
```

It's the easiest way to do it i think